# Menu Bar: Reverse lookup menu item by keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, menu-bar, search

### Searching the Menu Bar by Name

When using the search field in the Menu Bar's help menu, you can look up menu items for the current application by name. For instance, if I search for "Save" and hover over the first result, it will reveal that the menu item I'm looking for is under **File** > **Save**..., and its keyboard shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot of doing a Search by Name to locate a menu item]

### Reverse Searching the Menu Bar by Keyboard Shortcut?

Now here's the question: let's pretend I don't know what the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> does. I could just press it and see what happens, but ideally, I'd like to figure that out *before* I just go executing unknown commands willy-nilly. I've never heard of a way to reverse lookup a menu item using its shortcut, and the obvious things I've tried - searching for "command z", "cmd-z", with the Unicode symbol "⌘Z", or simply the letter "Z" - return nothing. Ideally, any of these searches would show me that the item I'm looking for is **Edit** > **Undo**, identically to if I had just searched for the word "undo".

Obviously, the examples I've used are very well-known and universal to almost any application; this would be a lot more useful in applications with lots of menu items and submenus, and many complex default keybinds. For instance, maybe I'd like to change or add a shortcut for a menu item through System Preferences, and I want to make sure that the key combo I want to use isn't already assigned to something else.

So, how can I search for a menu item by using the keybinding associated with the menu item?

Comment: If the question I added at the end is not to your satisfaction, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I think the closest you'll get is [CheatSheet](https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/)